# How to simplify the code and combine switch into one function?

Tags: c++

I have the task of getting the number of the variable `y` depending on which number worked in `first_number` and `second_number`

My version is working, but I have to constantly repeat the `switch`, in the end I have a lot of code, I'm very uncomfortable.

The problem is that the variable is different everywhere and I don’t know how to create a function where I can specify a number for each `case` block

```
switch (first_number)
{
    case 0:
    {
        switch (second_number)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                y = 13;
                cout << y << endl;
            }
            break;

            case 1:
            {
                y = 15;
                cout << y << endl;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    break;

    case 1:
    {
        switch (second_number)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                y = 3;
                cout << y << endl;
            }
            break;

            case 1:
            {
                y = 1;
                cout << y << endl;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    break;

    case 2:
    {
        switch (second_number)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                y = 156;
                cout << y << endl;
            }
            break;

            case 1:
            {
                y = 67;
                cout << y << endl;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encode the function as a table.

```
const int table[3][2] = {{13,15}, {3,1}, {156,67}};
int y = table[first_number][second_number];
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to simplify this. My goto solution often is `std::map`. It often isn't the most efficient container to choose, but it is extremely useful and performance is for later, when I know that I need to do something about it.

I dont fully understand what your code is supposed to do (also because some important details are missing), but I think you can use something like:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

void foo(std::pair<int,int> x) {
    static std::map<std::pair<int,int>,int> lookup_table{ 
        { { 1,1 }, 1},
        { { 2,3 }, 42}
    };
    std::cout << lookup_table[x] << '\n';
    // or 
    auto it = lookup_table.find(x);
    if (it != lookup_table.end()) {
        std::cout << it->second << '\n';
    }
}


int main(){
    foo( {1,1} );
}
```

The first variant, using `operator[]` will create an element in the map when the key cannot be found. I don't think this is what you want, so I included the variant using `find` that lets you check if an element for the given key exists in the map (and would also allow you to declare the `lookup_table` as `const`).

Last but not least, note that the above is far from being optimal. In the next step I would maybe consider to use an array and try to avoid the function local `static`. Nevertheless thats what would be my first approach.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you can't.

Imagine all your outputs are `a, b, c, d, e, f`. Each of your outputs requires a unique combination of inputs to result in one of the outputs. For example

```
0,0: a
0,1: b
1,0: c
1,1: d
2,0: e
2,1: f
```

Because all of your outputs are unique, the paths taken to them must also be unique. A fundamental thing with function logic is that the same inputs cannot have two different outputs. Here, you cannot have any reduction in combinations of inputs, because each of your outputs are unique, and thus having a shorter list of inputs would violate that rule.

This isn't barring something like a key-value map to reduce your code, but you won't be able to reduce the number of combinations needed to retrieve those values.

Comment: i dont understand how you arrive to the "you cant" conclusion, but that aside, " the same inputs cannot have two different outputs" is only true for pure functions (maybe not the right term, I am not too familiar with functional stuff), but in general a function can return different result for the same input without any problem. Consider `int foo(int y) { static int x = 0; return x+=y; }`. There is no such rule

Comment: `x` and `y` can both be considered inputs in that case.

Comment: no they cant. `x` is not visible from outside. Anyhow using a `static` variable is only one way to demonstrate it. How about `rand()` ? There are many more examples

Comment: rand() uses a mathematical function to generate a sequence of numbers, and will generate the same numbers in sequence when given the same seed. Just because your two examples don't have explicit argument inputs doesn't mean they "break" this rule.

Comment: I dont understand what you are arguing for. There is no such rule in general unless you refer to how a pure function is supposed to work. If I am wrong I would like to see a reference, so I can rectify my wrong understanding

Comment: I'm not arguing; I'm telling you that all computer systems today are [deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_system), it's literally a fundamental property of computers. If you provide any computer program with the same environment and exact set of inputs, you will receive a consistent output each and every time. Hopefully this will help you rectify your understanding

Comment: possibly you are not aware of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator

Comment: I am absolutely aware of that. Those rely on natural stochastic processes and have nothing to do with computers being deterministic models. Now who's being argumentative? Is OP using a hardware RNG to choose his outputs or are you just trying to feel correct at this point?